# How do I place a formula in column D for every stop sub?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have been tasked with creating a Spread Sheet to calculate how much time is spent in any given task. So far I have buttons set up to start and stop the clock but now i am stuck trying to add the following formula to each Stop Sub:

=text(A2-A3,HH:MM:SS)

Here is what I have so far:

```
' 
Sub StartTask()
'
Dim lr As Long
lr = Sheets(2).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Now()
Sheets(2).Range("b" & lr + 1) = "Task Name"
Sheets(2).Range("c" & lr + 1) = "Start"

End Sub


Sub StopTask()


Dim lr As Long
Dim lra As Range
Dim lrb As Range
'
lr = Sheets(2).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lra = Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr)
lrb = Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr - 1)
Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Now()
Sheets(2).Range("b" & lr + 1) = "Task Name"
Sheets(2).Range("c" & lr + 1) = "Stop"
Sheets(2).Range("d" & lr + 1).Formula = Text(lra - lrb, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

The formula is to find the amount of time spent in each task by subtracting the start time from the stop time. Every time Sub StartTask is run a new row is placed in sheet two, and every time Sub StopTask is run a new row is inserted in the row below that, and so on. this means that the formula needs to be placed in the same row as all the other data from Sub StopTask. I think the problem is that i am not defining lra and lrb correctly, but I'm not really sure. How can i place the formula in column D of each StopTask row?

Comment: change lra to `Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1)` and lrb to `Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr)` and it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is important to the data but using `"[hh]:mm:ss"` will allow showing a time greater than 24 hours. `"hh:mm:ss"` truncates off the 'less-than-a-day' portion so that 26 hours becomes 2 hours. Might not be mission critical in this situation but I always use the square brackets when displaying elapsed time rather than time-of-the-day.

Comment: @Jeeped In this case i hope that no one spends more than 24 hours in a task; however if someone were to forget to click the stop task button until the next day this may actually be a big help. Thanks a lot for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

```
Sub StopTask()


Dim lr As Long
Dim lra As Range
Dim lrb As Range
'
lr = Sheets(2).Range("a" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set lra =2 Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1)
Set lrb = Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr)
Sheets(2).Range("a" & lr + 1).Formula = Now()
Sheets(2).Range("b" & lr + 1) = "Task Name"
Sheets(2).Range("c" & lr + 1) = "Stop"
Sheets(2).Range("d" & lr + 1).Value = Format(lra - lrb, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

First if you look, you were referring to the wrong rows for your values.  Second text is a worksheet function.  Use format instead.

Comment: So this code gives me the error message "Object variable or with block variable not set". Being as I am a total novice i have no idea why it isn't working, and the Help function from microsoft confused me even more... thoughts?

Comment: The Object Variable or with Block vairable not set occurs because the set property has not been used in front of the range variables.

Comment: @ScottCraner You really are the man. Thanks so much for holding my hand through this.

Comment: @ScottCraner I realize that i need to learn more about the language that excel VBA uses. Can you recommend a good starting point? like a book, or possibly a college level class? This sight is amazing but i really want to go beyond copying and pasting other peoples code and cleaning up recorded macro code.

Answer (score 0):

placing formula:

`Sheets(2).Range("d" & lr + 1).Formula = "=Text(" & lra.Address & " - " & lrb.Address & ", ""hh:mm:ss"")"`

Comment: You need to comment out the variables. `"=Text(" & lra - lrb & ", ""hh:mm:ss"")"`